# Create Facebook Page via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to develop a Facebook App and i would like to create a Facebook Page through the Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Creating).

The problem is that looks like this feature is available only for "Standard API Access" which looks related to the Marketing API. How do I submit for revision (which looks necessary for use the API endpoint) my app for getting the "standard access api" if it is still under development?

Comment: Yes, that is part of the Marketing API, and you would need to apply for Basic level access first, and that requires among other things, that your _"App successfully makes at least 1000 API calls with an error rate of less than 10% in the last 30 days"_ and _"[...] creates sufficient ads that pass ad review and do not contain bad creatives"_ ... so if your app's purpose is not actually advertising on the FB platform, you can rather forget about that.